# Using project files in a Static Library

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6, static-libraries

i have created a static library for one of my project and used it in my another project (referenced as Main Project). Now i need to access some class files of my Main Project in the Static Library. Is this possible? and if yes how?

if you need more info please comment..

Thanks in advance!! :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to access the files from the static library. The only way is to get the xcode project or the archive from which the static library was built.

Comment: i have the lib project within my Main project.. but how can i allow lib files to access main project files?

Comment: The library that you are using is built from MHLib.xcodeproj right ?

Comment: Yes that is the project file for my library.

Comment: it should i know but it isn't. when try to import a .h file of my Main Project to library it show error as file not found.